Can we add any checks to restrict any particular type of transactions in transaction pool?
I am creating a mechanism to do the feeless transaction.
Even though I have implemented the feeless transaction, if the user is not eligible to do the feeless transaction, the user can still call the extrinsic and maybe crash the node. Is there any way we can add the checks before the transaction goes into the transaction pool?

how have you implemented a feeless transaction exactly? using #[pallet::feeless_if]?

I think you can make a storage and add the address that doesn't need to pay any fee and use it.

Yes, I used feeless_if in my solution.


if the user is not eligible to do the feeless transaction, the user can still call the extrinsic and maybe crash the node.

In this case, the validation itself will fail. This should not cause the node to crash.
